# YouTube видео в нативном HTML5 плеере

Tags: html5, youtube

Кто-нибудь пробовал проигрывать видео с YouTube в обычном HTML5 плеере? (нативный )

Вопрос, наверное, по заголовкам, вот есть ссылка на видео с YouTube допустим - "youtube.com/watch?v=naleynXS7yo"
Если вставлять её в тот же DownloadMaster какой-нибудь, то сервер, получается, отдает заголовки на скачивание файла
Видимо, downloadmaster отправляет какой-то определенный запрос на то, что хочет именно скачать файл?
Ну, типа как "Accept: application/json"
Вот думаю: может и на PHP как-то так же сделать с ютубом?
Просто не хочется на сервере размещать, а IFrame и вообще YouTube-вский плеер не подходит - нужно свои, кастомные субтитры вставлять.

Answer (score 2):

Нативного способа сделать это нет, но есть возможность добавить видео с помощью JavaScript. Для ваших целей, например, подойдет библиотека [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube)

С ее помощью можно вставлять видео как обычно

```
<video width="640" height="360" id="player1" preload="none">
    <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naleynXS7yo" />
</video>
```

Если браузер не поддерживает тег *video* будет использоваться Flash